# What's the relationship between eosio-abigen and eosiocpp?

Tags: smart-contract

I am running stable version `v1.1.2`
After running `eosio_build.sh`, there are one `eosio-abigen` executable which locate at `/build/programs/`  and another one is `eosiocpp` which locate at `/build/tools`

People normally use `eosiocpp` to generate the abi and wast files

Actually the abi generated by `eosiocpp` executable is show like this

```
  "____comment": "This file was generated by eosio-abigen. DO NOT EDIT - 2018-08-09T02:36:31",
  "version": "eosio::abi/1.0"
```

#### eosiocpp

[image]

#### eosio-abigen

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: [v1.2.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.2.0) confirms that `eosiocpp` has been deprecated:

> `eosiocpp` this multi-tool has been deprecated in this release and
>   will be removed in `v1.3.0`. It has been supplanted by on-going effort
>   in the `eosio.wasmsdk` repository

Also [documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/how-to-write-an-abi) on writing an ABI.

> As of v1.2.0, the eosio.wasmsdk was decoupled from the core
>   repository. This change has introduced an eosiocpp regression where
>   the legacy eosio-abigen is no longer bundled with eosio-cpp. Until a
>   new ABI generator is introduced, you will need to hand-write your ABI
>   files.

---

**Old answer:**

From Telegram (11th August, 2018):

> Todd Fleming: A quick summary on toolset status: eosiocpp (no hyphen)
>   is deprecated and no longer installed by default. It was a script.
>   eosio-cpp replaces it; it’s an executable, not a script, and is part
>   of wasmsdk. eosiocpp automatically invoked the old abi generator,
>   which is also deprecated. There are too many cases the old generator
>   couldn’t handle. The new abi generator is under development; it’s not
>   ready. For now, we recommend writing ABIs by hand.
>
> Todd Fleming: It generated a file with an .abi extension. You now have
>   to write that file yourself. It has a simple syntax, but no
>   documentation yet. Documentation is currently being written. Look
>   through the new contracts repo for .abi files to see examples.

So, to answer your question, neither tools are recommended to use anymore.