# How do I find and edit Hello.cpp?

Tags: eosio-code

I'm on a Mac, and working through the Hello World contract.

I managed to create the Hello.cpp file using the touch command in Terminal... but how do I find this file, and/or how do I edit it?

Comment: `touch` creates an empty file wherever you specify in the argument. you edit it with a text editor, but it'll be empty

Comment: I would like to edit it, but I don't know where the file is located on my Mac. I'm also using Docker to access cleos.

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal and go to  your home directory because it is the root directory of your all work directories . Go through this sequence

```
1.open terminal
2.# cd 
3.#locate hello.cpp
```

and you will find your file .
now open your file like this using vim like this

```
vim hello.cpp
```

press **i** (to edit your file )
after editing press **Esc**
than **Ctrl+Shift+:** and press **wq** (to save your file )
this will work if you have **vim** install to your system .

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use `eosiocpp` for the purpose of initiating your contract.

Just run:

```
eosiocpp -n hello
```

Then:

```
cd hello && ls
```

And you will see two files `hello.cpp` and `hello.hpp`.

This is the good way to start writing your contract from scratch.

Comment: `eosiocpp` is deprecated in latest version

Comment: @confused00 thank you for pointing this out. Did they move this functionality to another component?

Comment: `eosio-cpp` should be the replacement (see [todd fleming's telegram posts](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/whats-the-relationship-between-eosio-abigen-and-eosiocpp/1950#1950)) but haven't checked yet if they still have the `-n` flag